# Apache XMLSchema core XSD/XML parser shows the root element as parent for all children instead of its immediate parent

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xmlschema

I am trying to parse the `XSD` using `Apache XMLSchema Core`. I am able to parse the file and store the `Parent` and its `Child Element` information within the `HashMap`.

Each `Child` element is stored in the type `XmlSchemaElement` which also consists of the `Parent` information of that child element. When I try to see the information related to a child element it shows the `Root` element for all instead of its immediate parent.

For example: In my `XSD`, `RestaurantMenu` is the `Root` element and its immediate children are `Food`. Also, `Food` has childrens `name`, `price`, `calories` etc. When I see the parent element for `name` I would expect it to be `Food` as that's the immediate Parent but during `Debug` shows the `RestaurantMenu` as its parent which is a bit confusing.

I wanted to know how can I get the information related to the immediate parent for each element.

Following is my `XSD` file:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="RestaurantMenu">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="food" maxOccurs="5" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name" />
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="price" />
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description" />
                            <xs:element type="xs:short" name="calories" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Following is the code I have which is written using the `Apache XmlSchema Core XML Parser`:
I am trying to `Debug` at the point :

```
List<XmlSchemaElement> childElements = getElementType(new QName("food"));
System.out.println(childElements.get(0));
```

Above code will return all the `Children` element of food: `name`, `price`, `calories`, `description`, `ingredients`. Then I am trying to see the parent for one of the element i.e `name`. Following is the debug path I am taking:

```
childElements -> [0] -> namedDelegate -> parentSchema -> items -> [0] -> namedDelegate -> qName.
```

In this `qName` I was expecting the `food` as thats my immediate parent but I get the `RestaurantMenu` which is my `Root` xsd element.

Please find the complete code below:

```
public class TestParser {

    private static XmlSchemaCollection xmlSchemaCollection;
    private static Map<QName, List<XmlSchemaElement>> xsdElements = new HashMap<QName, List<XmlSchemaElement>>();
    private static List<XmlSchemaElement> schemaElements = new ArrayList<XmlSchemaElement>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // Path for the file which is stored within the Resource folder
        String xsdPath = Paths.get(TestParser.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.xsd").toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath();
        String filePath = Path.of(xsdPath).toString();

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        xmlSchemaCollection = new XmlSchemaCollection();

        // Schema contain the complete XSD content which needs to be parsed
        XmlSchema schema = xmlSchemaCollection.read(new StreamSource(is));
        // schema.write(System.out);

        // Get the root element from XSD
        Map.Entry<QName, XmlSchemaElement> entry = schema.getElements().entrySet().iterator().next();

        // Get all the elements based on the parent element
        XmlSchemaElement childElement = xmlSchemaCollection.getElementByQName(entry.getKey());

        // Call method to get all the child elements
        getChildElementNames(childElement);

        // Get the elements type based on choice
        List<XmlSchemaElement> childElements = xsdElements.get(new QName("food"));
        System.out.println(childElements.get(0));

    }

    // Method to check for the child elements and return list
    private static void getChildElementNames(XmlSchemaElement element) {

        // Get the type of the element
        XmlSchemaType elementType = element != null ? element.getSchemaType() : null;

        // Confirm if the element is of Complex type
        if (elementType instanceof XmlSchemaComplexType) {
            // Get all particles associated with that element Type
            XmlSchemaParticle allParticles = ((XmlSchemaComplexType) elementType).getParticle();

            // Check particle belongs to which type
            if (allParticles instanceof XmlSchemaSequence) {
                // System.out.println("Sequence Schema Type");
                final XmlSchemaSequence xmlSchemaSequence = (XmlSchemaSequence) allParticles;
                final List<XmlSchemaSequenceMember> items = xmlSchemaSequence.getItems();

                items.forEach((item) -> {
                    XmlSchemaElement itemElements = (XmlSchemaElement) item;
                    schemaElements.add(itemElements);
                    addChild(element.getQName(), itemElements);
                    // Call method recursively to get all subsequent element
                    getChildElementNames(itemElements);
                    schemaElements = new ArrayList<XmlSchemaElement>();
                });

            }
        }
    }

    // Add child elements based on its parent
    private static void addChild(QName qName, XmlSchemaElement child) {
        List<XmlSchemaElement> values = xsdElements.get(qName);
        if (values == null) {
            values = new ArrayList<XmlSchemaElement>();
        }
        values.add(child);
        xsdElements.put(qName, values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you simplify your question. There is far too much information there. If necessary, cut down your XSD and your code until they show _only_ the problem that you are asking about.

Comment: @kimbert Thanks for your response. I have reduced my `XSD` content and the code for better reading purposes. Hope this helps. Please have a look and let me know if you can suggest something for this issue as I am still looking for the answer.

Comment: Why would you expect parentSchema -> items -> [0] to contain the parent of a specific element? Surely, parentSchema represents the entire schema model, and parentSchema->items probably represents top-level declarations (or something). Suggest that you check your assumptions.

Comment: @kimbert Thanks for analyzing and providing your solution. Yes, I realized that later. I was looking at the `parentSchema` which may not contain the immediate parent for the element. If that does not contain then how can I obtain the parent element for the `child`? Is there any other alternative approach for getting the `immediate parentElement` for the child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working for some time on the `Apache XMLSchema Core` library in Java following is my observation.

There is no way to get the immediate parent directly using the library you can get the information related to the current element and its children from the XmlSchemaElement.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not an expert in XSModel, but I did use it once, a long time ago.

The XSModel is a full and complete record of almost everything in the XSDs. Therefore it does contain the information that you are seeking. It may help to realise that XSModel was created for the purpose of validating XML documents - it was never intended to be a general-purpose in-memory representation of an XSD model. If that's what you need then you will probably get on better with the [Eclipse XSD model](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.mdt.xsd). Either way, loading and manipulating XSD models is a minority sport and you should not expect the APIs to be perfectly documented.

> Can you please assist me in how to find an immediate parent for a child element within the Apache XMLSchema core library.

When you talk about a 'child element' I think you mean either a `local element declaration` or an `element reference`. In general, both of those can have *multiple* parent element declarations because they can be declared within a global complex type. If that global complex type definition is used by more than one element declaration then your 'child element' will have more than one possible parent element.

Comment: Thanks for the response and information. I am still seeking how to find the immediate parent for my child element. Can you please assist me in how to find an immediate parent for a child element within the `Apache XMLSchema core` library. I am aware that it contains my required information but I am not sure how and where exactly to find it. Hence I requested here hoping to get some response.

Comment: Answer updated. You have asked three separate questions about XSModel, but I still do not have a clear idea of what you are trying to accomplish. If you need further help, please ensure that your next question explains what your program is meant to do - we may be able to provide more useful answers if we understand what your technical goals are.